# I cannot install Kubuntu on Lenovo z50-75, Kubuntu logo is shown only

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu

I try to install Kubuntu on my Lenovo z50-75 laptop from USB drive (USB 2.0, capacity 16 GB). I want to make dual boot, now I have installed Windows 10 on it. I successfully started booting from device, then I choosed start Kubuntu option, some text was displayed and after that Kubuntu logo was displayed. I waited several tens of minutes, but nothing happened. I have done it several times, I have tried disabling secure boot and changing SATA mode in BIOS, but it didn't help.

Comment: Are you sure your USB is written properly? Did you check the iso signature?

Comment: Have you checked that USB in any other system?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I tried checking the medium option and it showed, that some files are corrupted. So I made new bootable USB and everything worked as I expected.